# React js - How to show search results in separate page using WordPress API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search

I have created search box in react where data is searchable form wordpress post api. i want to show this search results in separate page. from below code the page is redirecting to blank page

search.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Redirect } from '@reach/router';

class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: [],
      term: '',
    };

    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    this.changeTerm = this.changeTerm.bind(this);
  }

  changeTerm(event) {
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
  }

  submit(event) {
    let url = 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&search=' + encodeURI(this.state.term) + '&per_page=100';
    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        let data = {
          results: response.data,
        };
        this.setState(data);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submit} action="search/results">
          <input onChange={this.changeTerm} />
          <Button type="submit" bsStyle="primary">Find</Button>
        </form>
        {this.state.results.length > 0 &&
          <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/search/results',
            state: { results: this.state.results }
          }} />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

result.js

Comment: Do you actually want to redirect the user, or keep the user on the same page?  This is an odd mix of both.  You're using AJAX to perform the search, so presumably you want to keep the user on this page.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to redirect user after search on different page with search results